# How can I make a resizable flex item retain its aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, codepen

I have an effect on my website, and it only works within a 16:9 aspect ratio. This means I need to keep it within that aspect ratio. I wanted to make a box that was vertically and horizontally centered which could resize proportionally to contain the effect. I looked up many tutorials and guides on flex resizing, but i still cant get it to work properly. The padding in the  that contains the box is lopsided, and it doesnt align properly either. It scrolls horizontally even though im using 100vh/vw?? Does 100% of the viewport's height really mean what it says?

I'm really not sure what to do...

Codepen example of my code below:

https://codepen.io/Ktashi/pen/KKeOJey

html

```
<div class="flex-align">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-box"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-align {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.aspect-ratio-box {
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background: red;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 94vw;
  max-height: 94vw;
  max-width: 94vw;
}
```

I tried changing the flex-grow: property's value, along with flex-shrink: and flex-basis: but that didn't help much. I'm very stuck as I've only really been coding with html and css for about a year off and on.

Comment: Do you mean the max-height is to be 94vw?

Comment: @AHaworth The max-height is set to 94vw because the padding of the larger div is also using 1vw so the red box doesn't go all the way to the edges

Comment: But 94vw may be much larger than 94vh so I don't understand how that setting of itself would stop the element overflowing.

Comment: @AHaworth that is not the part that stops it from overflowing. 94vw on MAX-HEIGHT will not affect the current height and the aspect-ratio: property stops it from making the box bigger as well as it is set to 16/9

Comment: What stops overflowing?

Comment: @AHaworth there is only one flex item so it can not overflow in the first place. I'm sorry I meant wrapping

Comment: It does overflow if the viewport doesn't have enough height. Sorry, I can't see the logic in having the max-height set the same as max-width.

Comment: @AHaworth it doesnt really matter because it doesn't really relate to the bigger problems I'm having. I don't really understand why you  asked your initial question. And/or what it means

Comment: I just need the width to scale proportionally with the height to the width of the viewport. I don't think the max-height necessarily matters in this case.

Comment: I have lots of random css in there because I tried a lot of different things...

Comment: It depends on whether max-height or max-width take priority over aspect-ratio (I can't find a definitive reference). Anyway, I suggest dropping the maxs and using the flex purely to do the centering not the sizing.

Comment: @AHaworth I will get rid of the max height and width. I always have to thank people for not being unnecessarily rude one the internet so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS media query to test whether the item will fit within the parent which has 100vw/100vh dimensions.

This snippet is just to give the idea.

It does a couple of things - makes the parent's padding be part of its dimensions by setting box-sizing border-box and sets the height or width as % of the parent dimensions.

```css
.aspect-ratio-box {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  background: red;
}

@media (max-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9) {
  .aspect-ratio-box {
    width: 94%;
  }
}

@media (min-aspect-ratio: 16 / 9) {
  .aspect-ratio-box {
    height: 94%;
  }
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: black;
}

.flex-align {
  background: blue;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-align">
  <div class="aspect-ratio-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't of even thought to use media tags